# laravel middleware is not working in ajax request url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, middleware

I like to use ajax to insert into database and get back to show it.
I have ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
 method: 'POST',
 url: "{{ route('comments.store') }}",
 data: {
 comment: 1,
 comment_text: comment_text,
 post_id: post_id,
 "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
});
```

and in Url route('comments.store) is protect by middleware('auth')
in my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index']);
}

public function store( Request $request ) {
   if(Auth::check()){
      if ( isset( $request->comment ) ) {
         $comment = new Comment( [
         'comment' => $request->comment_text,
         'user_id' => Auth::id(),
         'post_id' => $request->post_id
      ] );
      $comment->save();
      $comments = Comment::find( $comment->id );
     return response( $comments );
    }
}
return redirect()->route( 'home.post.show', $request->post_id );
}
```

when the user is logged it worked normal and response $comment row.

but when user is not logged the middleware not redirect user to logging page and it response error "unauthenticated".

how to resolve it need help. Thanks You..

Comment: what is your middleware code

Comment: It is ajax request. Which do not auto redirect to any page. You need to check condition in success and then redirect using `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `error` callback function to your jQuery Ajax to redirect the user to the login page if Unauthorized

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "{{ route('comments.store') }}",
    data: {
        comment: 1,
        comment_text: comment_text,
        post_id: post_id,
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // User Not Logged In
        // 401 Unauthorized Response
        window.location.href = ' login page';
    }
});
```